# Putting a 100 pixel border at bottom of page

Tags: css

The CSS below makes a 100 pixel high border at the top of the page.  How could I make the same thing at the bottom of the page, when the user scrolls down to the bottom of the window?  (The bottom of the page is about 2000 pixels below the bottom edge of the browser window.)

```
body {
   border-top: 100px solid #DE2A00;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   }
```

Comment: If you want the border to always fall at least at the bottom of the browser's window, try [Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/).

Answer (score 1):

did you try adding the same declaration to the bottom border?

```
body {
   border-top: 100px solid #DE2A00;
   border-bottom: 100px solid #DE2A00;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `border-bottom: 100px solid #DE2A00;` to body.